# PDO Select returning nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to pull a list of items where the current category is equal to the category of the product, but when I try the below code, I get no items, despite having 6 entries in the database where the category of the item equals the current category name

```
$category_name = $_GET['category']; 
    $category_products = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category = :category_name");
    $category_products->bindParam(":category_name",$category_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $category_products->execute();
    $row = $category_products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
```

Comment: What is in `var_dump($row);`? Is category string? Because if is integer i.e. `1`, `2` etc this one is wrong also `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: var_dump($row) returns array(0) { }, $category_name is where the actual string for the category name is

Comment: Check the name to make sure `var_dump($category_name);`

Comment: In this case, var_dump($category_name); returns "Clothing", and the items I have in the database have a product_category of "Clothing" also

Comment: It is working here `array(7)....` tested on my server with table products..

Comment: Tested Poiz way, still not getting anything

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ do one of these for us

Comment: Okay, apparently somewhere in my code (probably in the part that lets you create a new category), a space is being added before and after the actual category name so it's " Clothing " instead of "Clothing"

Answer (score 1):

You may try doing it a little differently like the lightly commented snippet below demonstrates:

```
<?php

    // SANITIZE DATA FROM THE $_GET GLOBAL A BIT...
    $category_name      = isset($_GET['category']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['category'])): null;
    $row                = null;

    // CHECK THAT $category_name EXISTS FIRST....
    if($category_name) {
        $parameters         = array("category_name" => $category_name);
        $category_products  = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category = :category_name");

        // YOU MAY TRY PASSING THE NAMED PARAMETERS DIRECTLY AS AN ARRAY TO THE execute METHOD:
        $category_products->execute($parameters);
        $row                = $category_products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    var_dump($row);
```